# PC not on Network - How to connect to printer on network?

Tags: printing

Here's my situation: I am a consultant and just arrived at client's location where they have a network (Active Directory, etc.).  Is there any way for me to connect to their printers on the premises given the IP addresses?

What needs to be done?  Options?

My laptop is on a totally different domain and not connected at all to this company.

Do I need to get assigned another PC that is configured for this company's domain to connect to their printers?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the basic drivers for the printer from the manufacturer.
2. Use the Add Printer wizard in Windows
3. Select a local printer, not network
4. Create a new port and select Simple TCP/IP as the type
5. Enter the IP address
6. Complete the wizard by selecting the drivers you had downloaded and extracted in step 1.

If it doesn't work, the printer may require a special port type or have additional security settings.  In that case, contact your system administrator.

Comment: Or walk up to it and plug your laptop into the usb port on the printer? :P

Comment: +1 Depending on security, you may have to enter credentials to connect.  Naturally, talking to a local system adminsitrator would be a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the administrators at the site to give you the info you need, they have all the details ;-)

Comment: You really only need to answer the question once.  If made a mistake the first time, edit your answer, don't add a second answer.

Comment: better now? I deleted the first answer.